# MySql - How do I skip empty rows when updating back to wamp

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, foreach

I'm trying to make a button that updates the data entered in the datagridview back to my wampserver.

```
private void bt_form1_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Dataview.Rows)
    {
        string sqlSelectAll = "UPDATE klant SET Klant_ID = '" + row.Cells["Klant_ID"].
            Value + "', Voornaam = '" + row.Cells["Voornaam"].
            Value + "', Achternaam = '" + row.Cells["Achternaam"].
            Value + "', Adres = '" + row.Cells["Adres"].
            Value + "', Woonplaats = '" + row.Cells["Woonplaats"].
            Value;

        MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, con);
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting errors, apparently its cause cause this code tries to save the empty line at the bottom of the datagridview [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwPla.png) . Which is impossible as it is empty. How can I make it skip the last/empty row?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T5KZ.png
This error

Comment: Row.IsNewRow will indicate the new row. From your code in may be `if (! row.isNewRow)`

Comment: The answer provided by Furkan Kambay did get rid of the error. However, it doesn't save anything now, the cells are still empty after I restart it.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser JohnG, but unfortunately still getting the same error.
Guess my coding teacher doesn't know the source of the error either as he said its the empty line that's causing it.

Comment: Just found out that all data in a row is lost when i manually add a row in Wamp then edit this entry in the datagridview then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just there is no `'` at the end.

```
... + "', Woonplaats = '" + row.Cells["Woonplaats"].
        Value + "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes to your below will catch the new row and skip it.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Dataview.Rows)
{
  if (!row.IsNewRow) {
    string sqlSelectAll = "UPDATE klant SET Klant_ID = '" + row.Cells["Klant_ID"].
    Value + "', Voornaam = '" + row.Cells["Voornaam"].
    Value + "', Achternaam = '" + row.Cells["Achternaam"].
    Value + "', Adres = '" + row.Cells["Adres"].
    Value + "', Woonplaats = '" + row.Cells["Woonplaats"].Value;

    MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, con);
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  else {
    // new row skipped
  }
}
```